# Parse a smaller XML multiple times or a larger XML once using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

I am writing a process for an ASP.NET website which will look-up a certain value from an XML file and perform a redirect. I am using LINQ (C#) to parse this XML.

I have hit a decision point where I have to look-up alternate values within the same request. I have two solutions:

1. Look-up each value separately. This will mean parsing the XML twice. But the XML size will be much smaller
2. Store multiple values in the XML and parse XML once. This will make the XML larger.

So which approach will have less of a performance overhead considering this for a website with some concurrency?

Simply put should I parse 200 elements once OR 100 elements twice?

Comment: BTW the XML string is already cached in the Cache object.

Comment: Show us the linq queries. I'll tell you how to cache the full result set instead of the XML string :)

Comment: I cannot cache the result set as it could be different per request. Actually I cache the XElement itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fetched the results for both scenarios via my Linq query and then looped through the two XElements to determine which one I need to use. I just needed to think a bit more. So, now, I have a much smaller XML and a single look-up.

```
     IEnumerable<XElement> mping = (from mpings in mpingXML.Elements("mping")
                                           where mpings.Element("sptrn").Value.Equals(sourceURL, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                                           && (mpings.Attribute("lcl").Value.Equals(locale, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || mpings.Attribute("lcl").Value.Equals("ALL", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                                           select mpings);
```

Answer (score 2):

Neither. Cache the parsed result until it is changed (if ever).

Comment: I am caching the entire XML. But parsing the result of the Linq query is not possible since each request would yield a potentially different result set.

Comment: Well you app needs to do something. If LINQ to XML is not good enough, just load the data from an XML representation into some better data structure. You didn't show the structure, so it's hard to recommend something more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Why not parse it into memory once and then do lookups in-memory? E.g. read it into a Dictionary<> on your Application object. Put a FilesystemWatcher on the file and re-parse if it changed.

Comment: The XML is already in-memory. I am trying to optimize even further. Hence my question of size vs. two look-ups.

Answer (score 0):

My $0.02:

caching the XElement (and repeatedly query) that is good enough until your profiler tells you otherwise.